# Mygeneration Template Editor

Tags: c#, vb.net, mygeneration

i used mygeneration to generate my code,it is very helpful

but i found that the template editor is awful, and i dont have any substitution.

do u have any ideas? or better generator?(no CodeSmith, it is commercial)

thanks

:)

Comment: What language do you us in coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CodeFluent Entities](http://www.softfluent.com/trials).

It is commercial, though it's free for non-commercial use (Personal Edition).